# Batch rename multiple files with hyphenated names

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a series of files that I download/process regularly and need to use a batch file to rename. Each filename is something like word-word-word-datetime.csv. There is always a '-' between words and always -datetime before the '.csv' file extension. I need to remove the -datetime so that the files are named word-word-word.csv. In some cases there might be just one word before the -datetime but there can be a string of many words as well. I download these files and move them to a specific folder for processing, and there is already a batch file in the folder that I need to modify to also rename the files.

For example, I need the filenames below:

```
this-is-a-file-20200804134809.csv
another-file-20200804134750.csv
some-other-file-20200804134699.csv
file-20200804134389.csv
```

To be renamed to:

```
this-is-a-file.csv
another-file.csv
some-other-file.csv
file.csv
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462108/batch-renaming-files-after-certain-character) is almost exactly what I need, but I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to modify it for renaming files with multiple hyphenated words (code from linked answer copied below).

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B "*.mp4"') do (
    echo move "%%a-%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you look at removing the last fourteen characters of the basename instead.

Comment: @Compo: 15 last chars, to also include the last hypen...

Comment: Yes @Aacini, I should have engaged the brain, removing the hyphen too would mean fifteen characters, but the idea remains true. I would also suggest that `"*.mp4"` would be better as `"*-??????????????.csv"` and possibly piped to `findstr.exe`  with options similar to `/IR "\-[12][0-9]*\.csv$"`.

Comment: @Compo, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just to mention this: there are built in alternatives that allow you to create code that is easier to read and grasp than cmd scripts

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rename all of the .csv files in my folder, truncating the name to remove the last 15 characters as suggested by @Compo.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.csv) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-15!%%~xf"
)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you used the `if %%f neq %~nx0` part. There is no way that the running `.bat` file be selected by the `*.csv` wildcard...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more robust example, using the advice I provided in the comments:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A-D *-??????????????.csv ^
 ^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR ^
 "\-19[0123456789]*\.csv$ \-20[0123456789]*\.csv$"') Do (
    Set "BaseName=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "!BaseName:~,-15!%%~xG"
    EndLocal
)
```